# Operating System Not Found - BIOS recognizes, Live OS doesn't (Laptop)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, grub, multi-boot, mbr

Here's the deal:

I have a multi-partitioned hard drive on my laptop set up with GRUB. I got a blue-screen while working on Windows 7 and when rebooting I got the Operating System Not Found error message. I rebooted the computer once again and entered the BIOS setup just to see if recognized my HDD - it did. Next step for me was booting a Live CD and seeing if I could repair GRUB or at least check if something changed on the partitions, but it doesn't seem to recognize anything there. Tried blkid, fdisk -l, not even GParted can see it.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you saying your BIOS seems to recognize your hard drive, but nothing boots nor can you see that drive when booted from a LiveCD?

Comment: Exactly. One HDD already died on this laptop in the past but it was a different error, couldn't find the disk on boot, so the BIOS didn't see it/saw it dead. Now it's there but it somehow, at the same time, isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like your hard disk is distinctly unhappy.  Don't panic though...

2 ideas come to mind:

1) Some (all?) hard disk manufacturers provide software tools which you can burn onto a bootable CDROM.  You boot directly into the tool and then run some diagnostics which should hopefully provide some useful information on how to proceed.

For example, for Seagate disks there's [SeaTools for DOS](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools) (which is actually a bootable CDROM image).  Try Googling for " software diagnostic disk" or " disk utilities"

2) Could you try putting the disk in another computer?  Or, alternatively, you could get a USB hard disk enclosure to allow you to mount the disk on another computer over USB.

Comment: I'm pretty used to those things happening, I don't even sweat it anymore. I'm not a hardware expert, and since I believe this is a good HDD and the fact that I haven't had it for longer than a year, maybe something else is wrong?
Anyway, it's a Western Digital HDD, I'll try looking for their diagnostic tools. The biggest problem is that the BIOS recognizes it, but I can't look into the disk with fdisk or anything, and I don't actually have another laptop to test it.

Comment: Alright, my mistake. It's a Seagate ST9320325AS.

Comment: OK, cool - give SeaTools a shot and see if SeaTools can at least see your disk... let us know how you get on...

Comment: I'll burn the ISO right now and get back here with the results. In the meantime, I don't know if this makes any difference but here's the output of hdparm: http://pastebin.com/KCnmm0Wk

Comment: Hmm... looks like some other users are experiencing similar problems with the exact model disk that you have: http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Momentus-XT-Momentus-Momentus/ST9320325AS-not-detected/td-p/58309

Comment: Awesome! Just my luck, heh? Well, so I ran SeaTools but it didn't get far, told me it was unable to access the disk (despite it showing up there too) and told me to check the cables and power supply. I didn't have access to my thumb drive or I'd grab the log, but basically that was it. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried tightening the HDD but with no luck. Resetting to default on my BIOS got me an extra error message that didn't show up before Operating System not found. "PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable", which apparently is related to an attempt on network boot, and lurking around the web I found this: http://www.nocrash.com/ncbbs/msgs/3247.shtml which suggests a connection problem.

Posting some screenshots of the BIOS, proof of the recognition:
http://db.tt/FrUgnD4 and http://db.tt/jmQLLqn (these are jpegs in my Dropbox)

Comment: hmmm... I'm afraid the only thing I can think of is to try to use the disk on a friend's computer... or, and this is a real shot in the dark, try ensuring the the disk's onboard controller resets by taking the battery out of your laptop for a few minutes and try again.

Comment: I ordered a SATA case with an USB connector for 2.5" drives, it was pretty cheap and it seems like a great alternative to borrowing and meddling with a friend's laptop, isn't it? Anyway, I didn't really get what you meant but since I opened my laptop yesterday to check if something was loose, which includes taking it off any power supply, I guess we can rule that option out. Thanks, anyway! Now I'll just have to wait a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a utility like Test Disk to try a repair:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

First you need to rewrite the parition table, which will be similar to:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Data_Recovery_Examples#Two_FAT32_partitions_to_recover

Once you have done this you can then repair your GRUB installation.  The fact that the MBR is missing after a system crash is kind of concerning.  I would HIGHLY recommend backing up your data if you are able to access it again and then run diagnostics on the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to boot into it just so I can backup my data as soon as possible. I downloaded Test Disk but just like everything else (but the BIOS) it doesn't recognize the HDD.